# Too large line spacing with different font size (\tiny) in beamer

Tags: beamer, fontsize, line-spacing

When using the `\tiny` font in slides created with the `beamer` package I find that the spacing between lines in a wrapped paragraph is too large. (This only happens when mixing fonts within one paragraph.) How do I avoid this?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Large Text. And then smaller like so: \\
  {\tiny In mathematics, the method of considering a minimal counterexample (or minimal criminal) combines the ideas of inductive proof and proof by contradiction.[1] Abstractly, in trying to prove a proposition P, one assumes that it is false, and [...] 
  } \\
  (excerpt from \texttt{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal counterexample})
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Could you maybe accept the answer to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found the answer on comp.text.tex: You just need to add `\par` after the `tiny` text (and remove the `\\`) like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Large Text. And then smaller like so: \\
  {\tiny In mathematics, the method of considering a minimal counterexample (or minimal criminal) combines the ideas of inductive proof and proof by contradiction.[1] Abstractly, in trying to prove a proposition P, one assumes that it is false, and [...] 
  \par
  }
  (excerpt from \texttt{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal counterexample})
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is because the line spacing is calculated at the end of the paragraph. Without the `\par` the paragraph ends outside the `}` and thus outside the `\tiny`

Comment: So `par` is like ``\\`` but in addition tells LaTeX that it needs to (re-)compute the line spacing, right?

Comment: No `\par` is paragraph end, the definition of ``\\`` varies from the context it is being used. In normal text it is the same as `\newline`. However, 99% of all cases, a user should *never* use ``\\`` or `\newline` in the text.