# Too large line spacing with different font size (\footnotesized) in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I would like to decrease the font-size inside a tikz node.
I basically want a normal sized heading word, and then to put a multiline explination below it on `\footnotesize`d font.
But the fontsizing command won't apply across linebreaks.
And the linebreaks stay the original size

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, align=center](lexeme){Lexeme\\ \footnotesize e.g. \\ \footnotesize \{ go, going,\\ \footnotesize goes, went\}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of spacing not being right]

Closely related: [Too large line spacing with different font size (\tiny) in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142945/too-large-line-spacing-with-different-font-size-tiny-in-beamer), but that solution did not work for tikz

Comment: dirty hack: `\\[-0.7ex]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, align=center, font=\footnotesize](lexeme)
        {{\normalsize Lexeme}\\
         e.g.  go, going,\\
         goes, went};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```